# How to check max date in variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table `TEST` having column `computedate`. I want to check date in test table.

If there is no value then it should print a default `date(1900-01-01)`

```
DECLARE @CHKDT1 AS  DATE
SELECT @CHKDT1 = MAX(CONVERT(DATE,COMPUTEDATE,121))  FROM test

IF (@CHKDT1 = '' OR @CHKDT1 =  NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @CHKDT1 = CONVERT(DATE,'1900-01-01',121)
END
print @CHKDT1
```

Comment: First try to turn caps lock off.

Comment: Stop shouting!  You are scaring the code away!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @CHKDT1 AS  DATE
SELECT @CHKDT1 = MAX(CONVERT(DATE,COMPUTEDATE,121))  FROM test
select isnull(@CHKDT1, '1900-01-01')
```